# Execute a function in a new process (Cross-platform C++)

Tags: boost, wxwidgets, fork

So I'm trying to figure out an easy cross-platform way in C++ to execute a function in a new process. I'm using both Boost and wxWidgets, so solutions involving those would be awesome.

This is a really easy task on Posix - just need to fork() and then test whether we're the child or the parent. Unfortunately fork isn't available on Windows. wxWidgets provides an easy way to execute shell commands in a new process, but not functions (from what I've found). Boost (as far as I can tell) doesn't have any process manipulation tools.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How about starting a second thread instead of a new process?

Comment: I considered threads but decided against them (or would like to avoid them). I'm trying to write a simple plugin system with functions loaded from shared objects. I wanted to use separate processes so that a crash in a plugin didn't affect the core system.

Comment: You could have a look at rundll32, and putting your function(s) into a DLL

Comment: Yeah, worse case scenario I'll definitely slog through the Windows docs and write separate code for each platform, but I figured I'd ask since this seems like something you should be able to do with one of these cross-platform libraries.

Comment: wxExecute "Executes another program in Unix or Windows." I'm not sure it's possible to run a single function as another process. Doesn't a separate process need it's own address space, initialization, etc.?